# Python(2.6) cStringIO unicode support?

Tags: python, pycurl, stringio

I'm using python pycurl module to download content from various web pages. Since I also wanted to support potential unicode text I've been avoiding the cStringIO.StringIO function which according to python docs: [cStringIO - Faster version of StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO)

> Unlike the StringIO module, this module is not able to accept Unicode strings that cannot be encoded as plain ASCII strings.

... does not support unicode strings. Actually it states that it does not support unicode strings that can not be converted to ASCII strings. Can someone please clarify this to me? Which can and which can not be converted?

I've tested with the following code and it seems to work just fine with unicode:

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO

downloadedContent = cStringIO.StringIO()
curlHandle = pycurl.Curl()
curlHandle.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, downloadedContent.write)
curlHandle.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html')

curlHandle.perform()
content = downloadedContent.getvalue()

fileHandle = open('unicode-test.txt','w')
for char in content:
    fileHandle.write(char)
```

And the file is correctly written. I can even print the whole content in the console, all characters show up fine... So what I'm puzzled about is, where does the cStringIO fail ? Is there any reason why I should not use it?

[Note: I'm using Python 2.6 and need to stick to this version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any text that only uses ASCII codepoints (byte values 00-7F hexadecimal) can be converted to ASCII. Basically any text that uses characters not often used in American English is not ASCII.

In your example code, you are not converting the input to Unicode text; you are treating it as un-decoded bytes. The test page in question is encoded in UTF-8, and you never decode that to Unicode.

If you were to *decode* the value to a Unicode string, you won't be able to store that string in a `cStringIO` object.

You may want to read up on the difference between Unicode and text encodings such as ASCII and UTF-8. I can recommend:

- Joel Spolsky's [minimum Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Hmm, I still find it a bit confusing I guess I'll go google some more now... Basically I can not envision a case where I would get an error because I'm using cStringIO and not StringIO... In what scenario do I need to encode the bytes to unicode text ? Seems to me I can do any operation on the data as it is now(But I have to admit I have not tried anything... I'll experiment a bit now)... Btw, thanks for the ultra fast response ;)

Comment: *decode* to unicode text; the page has been encoded in UTF-8. And no, you don't need to decode, as your *parser* knows how to deal with encoded XML or HTML just fine.

Comment: Is there a possibility for some page to be encoded as unicode (UTF-16  I presume?). So if I crawl around I may potentially hit such a page and get an error because of trying to store in cStringIO?

Comment: @IvanKovacevic: No, because UTF-16 is still an encoding using simple bytes. Everything that can go in a file on the disk can go in a `cStringIO` object. Only the python unicode type can not be stored in such an object without encoding it to a bytestring first.

Comment: Aha, that's good... Basically what I want is to preserve the content I download to be exact as it is on the web server I download from... I thought about using io.BytesIO() but then I read that on Python 2.x that is only an alias for StringIO.StringIO() ... I'm not sure if that is true(read it somewhere on stackoverflow)... And I would love to use cStringIO if it is performance wise better. Or is there maybe something more ideal for this purpose?

Comment: No, `cStringIO` should be fine.