# Difference between cStringIO.StringIO.write and String.StringIO.write in Python

Tags: python

I gett following different result when using these two Class.

```
In [15]: StringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u2222')

In [16]: cStringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u2222')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a7a28c8bfb39> in <module>()
----> 1 cStringIO.StringIO().write(u'\u2222')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2222' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is any body know why and how it happens?

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801166/python2-6-cstringio-unicode-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for `cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO):

> Unlike the [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) module, this module is not able to accept Unicode strings that cannot be encoded as plain ASCII strings.